# React native Flatlist why all my items rerendered?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a simple list, where I can tap on an item that gets selected. If I tap on a new item, the selection changes to the new one. I am experimenting, how to create a component, where we dont rerender all array items on every selection? I would expect that only the previously selected, and the newly selected items should be rerendered. I have tried so many things, separating the components into different files, useMemo, useRef, useCallback etc. Is it even possible?

Here is what I have right now:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, memo } from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";

const ITEM_COUNT = 50;

const TapSelector = () => {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  const handlePress = useCallback((item) => {
    setSelectedItem((prevSelectedItem) =>
      prevSelectedItem === item ? null : item
    );
  }, []);

  const items = Array.from({ length: ITEM_COUNT }, (_, index) => ({
    id: index + 1,
    isSelected: selectedItem === index + 1,
  }));

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => {
      console.log(`Rendering item ${item.id}`);
      const backgroundColor = item.isSelected ? "#4CAF50" : "#FFFFFF";
      const textColor = item.isSelected ? "#FFFFFF" : "#000000";

      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor }}>
            <Text style={{ color: textColor }}>{`Item ${item.id}`}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    },
    [handlePress]
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={items}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      extraData={selectedItem}
    />
  );
};

export default memo(TapSelector);
```